# gem_package fails in Ruby 1.9.3 - undefined method 'full_name' for nil

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra, ruby-1.9.3

I'm using Chef to set up a node running Ubuntu 12.04. I wanted to use Ruby 1.9.3, including for Chef, and I'm using [this](https://gist.github.com/svanzoest/3947843) custom bootstrap file I found to accomplish it. (I previously tried using RVM in conjunction with Chef, and found that it caused problems at every turn - I was hoping this would be less error-prone.)

When I run the chef-client on this node, it reaches the point of attempting to install my Rails application, tries to install Bundler, and fails, thus:

```
Recipe: <Dynamically Defined Resource>
  * gem_package[Bundler] action install
================================================================================
Error executing action `install` on resource 'gem_package[Bundler]'
================================================================================


NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application_ruby/providers/rails.rb

162:     gem_package gem do
163:       action :install
164:       source src if src
165:       version ver if ver && ver.length > 0
166:     end
167:   end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/application_ruby/providers/rails.rb:162:in `block in install_gems'

gem_package("Bundler") do
  provider Chef::Provider::Package::Rubygems
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  package_name "Bundler"
  version ">1.3"
  cookbook_name "tiptap_api"
end
```

To attempt to isolate the problem, I placed the following call to `gem_package` in the recipe before the deployment attempt:

```
gem_package 'Bundler' do
  version '>0'
  action :install
end
```

This, too, fails, in the same way.

I found that the `gem` executable installed by apt-get was actually named `gem1.9.1`. I thought that this might be the problem, and renamed it to `gem`. Once that was done, I could run `sudo gem install bundler` normally and without any problems, but the chef-client still produces this error.

What's going on, how can I fix it, and why is this error message so terrible?

Comment: `"bundler"` is not the same as `"Bundler"`. Case matters!

Comment: @HolgerJust One the one hand, I now feel like an idiot. On the other hand, my problem is solved, and if you want to make that an answer, I'll happily accept it.

Comment: Don't feel that way. Sometimes all that's required is just another pair of eyes to spot the obvious :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your stack trace, it seems like you want to install a gem called `Bundler`. However, this gem doesn't exist which results in the error you observe. You probably want to install the `bundler` gem instead. Case generally matters in the Ruby world :)

While it is true that the error message is rather misleading, the reason for that is probably that the case of a non-existing gem is not explicitly checked by Chef and thus assumptions in later stages of the code just break resulting in the strange error.

This in turn might be considered a bug in Chef that you might want to report on http://tickets.opscode.com/ (at least if that still is an issue in the most current version of Chef, I haven't checked that).

Comment: In general, if your gem repository doesn't have the gem you're trying to install, this error will show up. We are using a private repository so we ran into this cryptic message.